# Restart a non responsive router remotely

Tags: networking

I have a Trendnet TEW-810DR that is currently in a loop giving itself a high load. It is currently acting as my main DHCP and Gateway servers. It has a direct IP connecting it. Currently I am able to teamviewer into a computer beneath it, but not RDP. When I go to the router's configuration page, it takes ~3 minutes to connect and receive page, and attempting login times out (and throws a 500 error). I currently do not have access to the router, so I cannot reboot it physically. Is there another possible way to reboot it or kick it out of it's loop?

It was brought into it's loop when I attempted to enable its response to pings from the internet, if that says anything. Not sure what caused trendnet's firmware to glitch on that.

Anyway's I need my gateeway running again so I can RDP/webserver/other services I host, that is currently down because of this.

Thanks,
Tommy

Comment: I have heard of a mains plug that can be turned on/off remotely.

Comment: "web power switches" are commonly available, http://www.ambery.com/pr2reposwweb.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how physically far away you are from the router, a remote control power switch can do the job in some cases. If you are out of range then your best option is to purchase a remote IP power switch which lets you login to it's interface and physically switch the connected devices on and off - some even have a pinger which switches off/on after it has not recieved a ping reply after a pre-determined time.

Also find out if the router has SSH capability or Telnet access. If it has then it's a simple case of logging in and typing reboot.

Comment: Sadly I am currently 327 Miles away from the router until around the beginning of January, so I cannot install any hardware right now. I also scanned the open services on my router locally, and it came up with 25, 80, 110, and  119, none which is being useful in any way.

Comment: you may be able to use autohotkey to automatically login and reboot router at a set time once a day - this may make things more stable...

Comment: I may do that when I get it working again, but sadly right now when I attempt to log in, it gives a 500 error and says the system is busy.